# norm of vectors u, and v transposed

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

given vectors $u$ and $v$ in $R^n$ how do i prove that

$||uv^T||_2 = ||u||_2 ||v||_2$

is it sufficient to just calculate?

$||u||_2 = \sqrt{u^2_1+u^2_2} $

$||v||_2 = \sqrt{v^2_1+v^2_2} $

do i just multiply $u$ and $v^T$ and take the vector norm? or do i take the matrix norm here? or am i totally wrong and misunderstood the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no theorem that says that for any two matrices $\lVert AB\rVert_2=\lVert A\rVert_2\lVert B\rVert_2$, because in general $\lVert AB\rVert_2\ge\lVert A\rVert_2\lVert B\rVert_2$ is false.

Comment: If you "just multiply $u$ and $v^T$", what kind of object do you get as a result?

Comment: "or do i take the matrix norm here?" Yes, on the left hand side.

Comment: @DavidK one get a matrix, which is why i wondered if we take the matrix norm. which seems to be the case since like amsmath confirmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may begin with the definition of the operator norm:
$$
\|uv^T\|_2=\max_{\|w\|_2=1}\|uv^Tw\|_2.
$$
Since $v^Tw$ is a scalar, we get
$$
\|uv^T\|_2=\max_{\|w\|_2=1}|v^Tw|\|u\|_2
$$
and you may continue from here.

**Edit.** One may also begin with the equivalent definition that $\|A\|_2=\sqrt{\rho(A^HA)}$. In this case we have
$$
\|uv^T\|_2^2=\rho(vu^Tuv^T)=\|u\|_2^2\rho(vv^T)
$$
and it remains to prove that $\rho(vv^T)=\|v\|_2^2$. This should be easy if you consider the images of $v$ and $v^\perp$ under $vv^T$.

Comment: Im sorry to say I dont quite understand what "operator" means. About the defintion of matrix norm in my textbook it says: $||A||_2 = sqrt\{p(A^H A} $ where p is the spectral radius.

Comment: @kayaya10 That's the name of the norm. And the definition in your textbook is equivalent to the one here.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped out!